# A recursive selection sort for a linked list by swapping node links instead of swapping values-C++

Tags: c++, recursion, linked-list, selection-sort

I'm trying to write a selection sort for a singly linked list recursively and having trouble when I want to swap two nodes.
Here is my swap function:

```
void swapNode(ListNode** head_ref, ListNode* min, ListNode* prevMin, ListNode* head){
  *head_ref = min;

  ListNode* temp = min->next;
  min->next = head->next;
  head->next = temp;

  prevMin->next = head;

}
```

And then it went into an endless loop.
When I changed the last line "prevMin->next = head;" into the second line like this:

```
void swapNode(ListNode** head_ref, ListNode* min, ListNode* prevMin, ListNode* head){
  *head_ref = min;
  prevMin->next = head;

  ListNode* temp = min->next;
  min->next = head->next;
  head->next = temp;

}
```

Everything works out fine. Could anyone see the reason here?

Here is my selection sort function, inside which the swapNode is called:

```
ListNode* selectionSortLL(ListNode* head){
  if(head == NULL || head->next == NULL) return head;
  ListNode* cur = head;
  ListNode* min = head, *prevMin = NULL;
  while(cur->next){
    if(cur->next->val < min->val){
      min = cur->next;
      prevMin = cur;
    }
    cur = cur->next;
  }

  if(min != head){
    swapNode(&head, min, prevMin, head);
  }

  head->next = selectionSortLL(head->next);
  return head;
}
```

Comment: Draw it all out on paper, using boxes for the nodes and arrows for the links. If you do it for the initial (non-working) function does the drawing make sense? For things like trees or lists it usually helps to draw things using pen and paper first, and then translating the manipulations you do on the paper into code.

Comment: In particular, the case in `swapNode` where `prevMin` and `head` are the same looks bad.